# How to detect running ASP.NET version

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I see the version of .net framework which renders my aspx page on remote server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This outputs your version:

```
System.Environment.Version.ToString()
```

Comment: No, that's the running .NET framework version, not the ASP.NET version.

Comment: @Quandary You did not read his actual question, which is to figure out which version of the .NET framework renders his page.

Answer (score 4):

```
<%@ Page language="C#" %>
<% Response.Write(".NET Framework Version: " + Environment.Version.ToString()); %>
```

Answer (score 3):

[Environment.Version](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.version)

Answer (score 1):

#### Enable Trace

Enabling Trace is another option view every details of rendered page, including .NET Version
Add **Trace="true"** in page directive

```
<%@ Page Trace="true" %>
```

Scroll down to bottom and you will see rendered .NET Version

Comment: Thank you. The shortest code will do all needed: <%@ Trace="true" %>

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you all got the CLR version (but not really either, you actually get a string that is hard-coded in mscorlib.dll).

For the actual ASP.NET version, as you see it on the YSOD error pages, see here (they are NOT the same):

```
using System;


namespace MyElmahReplacement
{


    public class MyVersionInfo
    {


        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string strModuleName);

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern int GetModuleFileName(IntPtr ptrHmodule, System.Text.StringBuilder strFileName, int szeSize);



        private static string GetFileNameFromLoadedModule(string strModuleName)
        {
            IntPtr hModule = GetModuleHandle(strModuleName);
            if (hModule == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                return null;
            }

            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(256);

            if (GetModuleFileName(hModule, sb, 256) == 0)
            {
                return null;
            }

            string strRetVal = sb.ToString();
            if (strRetVal != null && strRetVal.StartsWith("\\\\?\\"))
                strRetVal = strRetVal.Substring(4);

            sb.Length = 0;
            sb = null;

            return strRetVal;
        }


        private static string GetVersionFromFile(string strFilename)
        {
            string strRetVal = null;

            try
            {
                System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo fviVersion = System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(strFilename);
                strRetVal = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", new object[] {
                    fviVersion.FileMajorPart,
                    fviVersion.FileMinorPart,
                    fviVersion.FileBuildPart,
                    fviVersion.FilePrivatePart
                });
            }
            catch
            {
                strRetVal = "";
            }

            return strRetVal;
        }


        private static string GetVersionOfLoadedModule(string strModuleName)
        {
            string strFileNameOfLoadedModule = GetFileNameFromLoadedModule(strModuleName);

            if (strFileNameOfLoadedModule == null)
                return null;

            return GetVersionFromFile(strFileNameOfLoadedModule);
        }


        public static string SystemWebVersion
        {
            get
            {
                return GetVersionFromFile(typeof(System.Web.HttpRuntime).Module.FullyQualifiedName);
            }
        }


        public static bool IsMono
        {
            get
            {
                return Type.GetType("Mono.Runtime") != null;
            }
        }


        public static string MonoVersion
        {
            get
            {
                string strMonoVersion = "";

                Type tMonoRuntime = Type.GetType("Mono.Runtime");
                if (tMonoRuntime != null)
                {
                    System.Reflection.MethodInfo displayName = tMonoRuntime.GetMethod("GetDisplayName", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static);
                    if (displayName != null)
                        strMonoVersion = (string)displayName.Invoke(null, null);
                }

                return strMonoVersion;
            }
        }


        public static string DotNetFrameworkVersion
        {
            get
            {
                // values.Add(ExceptionPageTemplate.Template_RuntimeVersionInformationName, RuntimeHelpers.MonoVersion);
                if (IsMono)
                    return MonoVersion;

                // Return System.Environment.Version.ToString()
                return GetVersionOfLoadedModule("mscorwks.dll");
            }
        }


        public static string AspNetVersion
        {
            get
            {
                //values.Add(ExceptionPageTemplate.Template_AspNetVersionInformationName, Environment.Version.ToString());
                if (IsMono)
                    return System.Environment.Version.ToString();

                return GetVersionOfLoadedModule("webengine.dll");
            }
        }


        public static bool IsVistaOrHigher
        {
            get
            {
                System.OperatingSystem osWindowsVersion = System.Environment.OSVersion;
                return osWindowsVersion.Platform == System.PlatformID.Win32NT && osWindowsVersion.Version.Major >= 6;
            }
        }


        public static void Test()
        {
            string ErrorPageInfo = 
                string.Format("Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version: {0}; ASP.NET Version: {1}"
                    ,DotNetFrameworkVersion
                    ,AspNetVersion
            );

            Console.WriteLine(ErrorPageInfo);
        }


    } // End Class MyVersionInfo


} // End Namespace LegendenTest
```